# C++ Python interpreter - Py_Initialize is crashing

Tags: python, c++

I have compiled the python source code for 32bit and am trying to use the `Py_Initialize()` API to init the python interpreter in my C++ application.
`Py_Initialize()` leads to below crash.  Please help me how to solve on this.

Am compiling my code like below:

```
g++ ./Pythoninterpreter.cpp -m32 -lpthread -ldl -lutil /usr/lib/libm.a /usr/lib/libpython2.7.a -Xlinker -export-dynamic -I/root/python_tar/Python-2.7.6/Include -I/root/python_tar/Python-2.7.6 -o pythonintepreter

gdb back trace
===============

#0  0x080e8ba7 in va_build_value (format=0x8152ec1 "", va=0xffed7564 "\240\344\027\b\244y\355\377", flags=0) at Python/modsupport.c:521
521         memcpy(lva, va, sizeof(va_list));
(gdb) bt
#0  0x080e8ba7 in va_build_value (format=0x8152ec1 "", va=0xffed7564 "\240\344\027\b\244y\355\377", flags=0) at Python/modsupport.c:521
#1  0x080e8ca6 in Py_BuildValue (format=0x8152ebe "[O]") at Python/modsupport.c:485
#2  0x080a77a7 in mro_implementation (type=0x817e4a0) at Objects/typeobject.c:1605
#3  0x080a3d68 in mro_internal (type=0x4) at Objects/typeobject.c:1636
#4  0x080a4723 in PyType_Ready (type=0x817e4a0) at Objects/typeobject.c:4057
#5  0x080a5186 in PyType_Ready (type=0x817e3c0) at Objects/typeobject.c:4005
#6  0x08088252 in _Py_ReadyTypes () at Objects/object.c:2071
#7  0x080ee3f4 in Py_InitializeEx (install_sigs=1) at Python/pythonrun.c:191
#8  0x080eee32 in Py_Initialize () at Python/pythonrun.c:382
#9  0x080598fe in PythonIntepretor::PythonIntepretor(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned short) ()
#10 0x080595fe in main ()
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure of what you want to do since you didn't provide the code on PythonInterpreter.cpp.

The following code compiles with the command line:

g++ -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -o foo foo.cpp -lpython2.7

```
#include  "Python.h"
int main()
{
  Py_Initialize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: am just doing the same thing.  But it crashes.  And FYI, I have compiled the python source code for 32 bit architecture.  With 64bit, even am able to run the code successfully

Comment: I compiled the python source code with 32bit architecture. the python binary produced as part of the compilation also throws the same error.